Layout and item colors work fine in Running Devices Emulators, but when try to run same app in my XIAOMI, colors are not working
Layout and item colors work fine in Running Devices Emulators, but when try to run same app in my XIAOMI, colors are not working. I presume the code is well done, because in emulators everything works fine, but when I try to run in my phone (XIAOMI) colors are not working as supposed to do.
try several times and always same result. Tried on a Samsung Galaxy, and it works fine (correct colors)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
